# Room database migration with missing 1.json schema file

Tags: android, android-room, android-room-migration

I am about the migrate my room database from 1 to 2.
In version 1 `exportSchema` was set to `false`. I was unaware of the impact at the time.
Therefore no 1.json schema file is available on device running the app so far.

In version 1 there is a class, let's call it Mango as follows:

```
@Entity(tableName="mango)
data class Mango(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int =0,
    val carbs: Float = 0f
){...}
```

In version 2 the field `carbs` should change to `carbohydrate`. This is how I do it in my `RoomDatabase` class.

```
@Database(
    entities = [Mango::class], version = 2, exportSchema = true
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
...
        fun getDatabase(
        context: Context
    ): AppDatabase {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "my_database"
            ).addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }
 ...

val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Mango RENAME COLUMN cabrs TO carbohydrate")
}
```

It works on emulator in android studio. And this is how I test it.

1. Uninstall the app
2. Run version 1
3. Switch code to version 2 and run version 2

Result: Working

I have created a release version and sent it via google play to test it in a real life stuation, and I get the following error when I update the app with the new version 2:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 
1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE Mango RENAME COLUMN carbs TO carbohydrate
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE Mango RENAME COLUMN 
carbs TO carbohydrate).
```

If it is because of the missing 1.json file, then how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is because of the missing 1.json file, then how can I fix this?

The issue is probably not the schema but is probably that the *"real life run"* was on an android version that doesn't include release 3.25.0 or greater of SQLite.

- Typically unsupported features result in a Syntax Error that can be confusing is it tends to mention where the error was found  as it doesn't know about the new syntax.

i.e. only devices with API 30+ (when a jump was made from 3.22.0 to 3.28.0)

as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary

[SQLite 3.25.0 release documentation](https://sqlite.org/changes.html):-

**2018-09-15 (3.25.0)**

- Add support for window functions
- Enhancements the ALTER TABLE command:

  - **Add support for renaming columns within a table using ALTER TABLE table RENAME COLUMN oldname TO newname.**
    -Fix table rename feature so that it also updates references to the renamed table in triggers and views.
- ....

If you need to target devices less than API 30, then you may not be able to use AutoMigration but will instead have a manual migration that:-

1. renames the original table
2. create the new table (copy the SQL from the `createAllTables` method in the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl** that can be found in the java(generated) via the Android View (I believe CRTL B can also be used)).
3. then execute the SQL  `INSERT INTO <new_table> SELECT * FROM <the_renamed_original_table>`

   1. Note that this assumes that the columns are in exactly the same position. It would be safer to use `INSERT INTO new_table (<ALL_THE_COLUMNS_NAMES_OF_THE_NEW_TABLE_COMMA_SEPARATED>) SELECT (<THE_RESPECTIVE_COLUMNS_OF_THE_RENAMED_TABLE_COMMA_SEPARATED>)`

- Note anything enclosed within `<` and `>` should be changed accordingly, the enclosed text explains the change(s)
- Note the above is in-principle code, it has not been compiled/run or tested so may contain some minor errors.

Comment: Hi @MikeT, thanks for the great answer. The device with the error is indeed running with API 26. I will follow your suggestion and I hope it will fix it.